# Is there a way to allow for slashes in an angular 2 route?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I'm developing an angular 2 app, and I want my routes to look like the following.

```
/metadata/:path
/data/:path
```

Etc....

The problem is, my ":path" variable is going to be a file path with slashes. Something like this.

```
/foo/bar/baz
```

So in my component's ngOnInit, I've got some code like this.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pathSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params['path']);
    });
}
```

For a route like this

```
/metadata/foo
```

The logged output is "foo"

However, when I attempt to do something like this

```
/metadata/foo/bar
```

I get an error, because there is no child route named "foo". I would instead like "/foo/bar" to be interpreted as the parameter ":path".

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can use a custom https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSerializer-class.html or you can use a `**` child route and parse the path there. This will only work if `:path` is always at the end of the path.

Comment: Could I use query parameters after the path? Something like this

/metadata/foo/bar/baz?time=next

Comment: Sure, but no other path segments `/xxx` that you need to be processed by the router.

Comment: Sweet. I'll give it a shot

Comment: Soo, how did you solve the problem? I have a similar need in my app ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I had more pressing matters, so I stuck with escaping my slash based route parameters for the time being. I'm planning on coming  back and fixing the routes if I have the time.